# Is it possible to set the orientation of the lock screen to landscape in Nexus 7?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, lockscreen, nexus-7

I want the home screen and the lock screen to be in the landscape mode. I used [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devasque.rotationlocker&hl=en) and able to make the home screen to stay in landscape mode but the lock screen is still in the portrait mode. I would like to know how this app changing the orientation of the home screen and is it possible to change the orientation of lock screen to landscape without installing some other third party lock screen.

I am only looking for the solution that works on Nexus 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has released a new version for Nexus 7 Android 4.1.2 which supports both home screen and the lock screen in the landscape orientation. Please update your software..